# How to prevent two signals from overlapping?

Tags: pine-script

I created three divergence signals and created a signal indicator on the chart. However, when three signals occur simultaneously, the signal symbols overlap, making it difficult to identify. How can I avoid overlapping when three signal symbols occur at the same time?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTfKG.png)

I want the signal symbols to be arranged side by side like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KkHg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lifting method described [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-lift-plotshape-text-up).

```
//@version=4
study("Lift text", "", true)
// Use U+200E (Decimal 8206) as a non-printing space after the last "\n".
// The line will become difficult to edit in the editor, but the character will be there.
// You can use https://unicode-table.com/en/tools/generator/ to generate a copy/pastable character.
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowup,      location.abovebar, color.green,     text="A")
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowup,      location.abovebar, color.lime,      text="B\n‎")
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowdown,    location.belowbar, color.red,       text="C")
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowdown,    location.belowbar, color.maroon,    text="‎\nD")
```

[image]